# Memory leaks in angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am looking into memory leaks caused by angular 1.5 in my app. I found these great articles:

[How to create giant memory leaks in AngularJS](https://makandracards.com/makandra/31289-how-to-create-giant-memory-leaks-in-angularjs)

[Fixing Memory Leaks in AngularJS and other JavaScript Applications](http://www.dwmkerr.com/fixing-memory-leaks-in-angularjs-applications/)

But I am still unable to find the causes of memory leaks in my application although I am following all the rules describe in these articles.
I am using this directive. Maybe it is the cause of memory leaks?
[angular-dialgauge](http://github.com/cdjackson/angular-dialgauge)

Comment: Start removing things, one by one, until the memory leaks stop, to find which part of your application causes it

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell anything specific without any code, and I guess you're not sure where it comes from since you would fix it if you did, but in general, my experience was that using `$rootScope` for anything that's not really necessary will cause you headaches in long run, so I'd start from there. You can maybe use something like this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-watchers/nlmjblobloedpmkmmckeehnbfalnjnjk?hl=en to check if listeners are getting pilled up over time.

Also good info would be how much memory your app consumes on load, and how fast it grows

Comment: I am using this directive. Maybe it is the cause of memory leak?
https://github.com/cdjackson/angular-dialgauge

Comment: This uses `$scope.$watch`  heavily, which as far as I remember AngularJS means that it will check watched variable in every digest cycle (which is a lot). So this could be the problem. Can you try without it

Comment: I am using this directive a lot in my appliction. My app won't work without it.

Comment: @mariazahid can the running app be shown somewhere without seeing it and being able to use the developer tools on the site it's impossible to say what is wrong, there is no silver bullet to performance problems.  Every {{}} binding in the view creates a watcher, they are not in general a problem until you have 10s of thousands of them, there are some simple things you can do like one time binding {{::bindOnce}} syntax but depending on the actual app the watchers may be a red herring, you need to profile the code to see what is going on.